# Django - Get query parameters and put it into list of dictionary

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-views, pycharm

I have a `GET` query the format is like this:

```
?title1=a&test1=b&title2=a&test2=b&..&titleN=a&testN=b
```

The view contains just the code above

```
def index(request):
    # This is my view
    print request.GET.items():
```

This is the result returned I got from the view when I run the query :

```
{ 'title1':'a', 'test1':'b', 'title2':'a', 'test2':'b','titleN':'a', 'testN':'b' }
```

I want to create a new list of dictionary.

```
[
    {
        'title1' : 'a' , 
        'test1':'b'
    }, 
    {
        'title2' : 'a' ,
         'test2':'b'
    },
    {
        'titleN' : 'a',
        'testN':'b'
    }
]
```

As you can notice I want to arrange all the data by number and **N** here is a **Number**

The question is how to make a list like I mentioned above ,
the only convention is the dictionary contains keys with the same last number .

And then I want the list  become like this :

```
[
    {
        'title' : 'a' , 
        'test':'b'
    }, 
    {
        'title' : 'a' ,
         'test':'b'
    },
    {
        'title' : 'a',
        'test':'b'
    }
]
```

Comment: Does your dictionary have _all_ numbers between 1 and N?

Comment: Yes, it ends with a number and it contain a word like the example mentioned above the only important thing it's the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one doesn't depend on the order of the items

```
import itertools
import re
num = re.compile('[0-9]+')
alpha = re.compile('[a-z]+')
query = { 'title1':'a', 'test1':'b', 'title2':'a', 'test2':'b','titleN':'a', 'testN':'b' }

result = [dict((num.sub('', w[0]), w[1]) for z, w in v) for i, v in itertools.groupby(((alpha.sub('', k), (k, v)) for k, v in query.items()), lambda x: x[0])]

# result:
# [{'test': 'b', 'title': 'a'},
#  {'test': 'b', 'title': 'a'},
#  {'testN': 'b', 'titleN': 'a'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve the problem is to use regulare expressions for extracting the number and then `itertools` for grouping by that number.

```
import re, itertools

# This is the grouper function; used first for sorting, 
# then for actual grouping

def grouper(key):
    return re.findall(r'\d+$',key[0])[0]

# Sort the dictionary by the number
sorted_dict = sorted(original_dict.items(), key=grouper)

# Group the sorted dictionary items and convert the groups into dicts
result = [dict(vals) for _,vals in (itertools.groupby(sorted_dict, key=grouper))]
#[{'title1': 'a', 'test1': 'b'}, 
# {'title11': 'a', 'test11': 'b'}, 
# {'title2': 'a', 'test2': 'b'}]
```

Comment: in the result what does the dict(vals) contain ?

Comment: It converts a list of tuples into a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to python what is the role of _ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python

Comment: @SelimAjimi It is convention in python to use `_` for variable which won't be used

Comment: I got an error in 
result = [dict(vals) for _,vals in (itertools.groupby(sorted_dict), key=grouper)]

On key=grouper and also x is not defined in the grouper function

Comment: There were two minor typos.

Comment: The solution works fine However if the query not passed without any ending number it ends with an error is there any solution . This is only for security reason.

Comment: Shouldn't that have been checked at the time of costructing the original dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the test and title will be holding integer suffix in continuous series of numbers starting from 1, below is a possible approach via using *list comprehension* to achieve this:

```
>>> my_dict = { 'title1':'a', 'test1':'b', 'title2':'a', 'test2':'b','title3':'a', 'test3':'b' }
>>> n = int(len(my_dict)/2)

>>> [{'title{}'.format(i), my_dict['title{}'.format(i)], 'test{}'.format(i), my_dict['test{}'.format(i)],} for i in range(1, n+1)]
[{'test1', 'b', 'a', 'title1'}, {'b', 'test2', 'a', 'title2'}, {'b', 'a', 'title3', 'test3'}]
```

---

I will suggest that instead of passing params to your apis as:

```
title1=a&test1=b&title2=a&test2=b
```

you should be passing it as:

```
title=a1,a2,a3&test=b1,b2,b3
```

The reason is: all the values should be mapped with single *title* and *test* parameter.

In this case, your code should be:

```
title = request.GET['title']
test = request.GET['test']

my_list = [{'title{}'.format(i): ti, 'test{}'.format(i): te } for i, (ti, te) in enumerate(zip(title, test))]
```

where value hold by `my_list` will be:

```
[{'test0': 'b1', 'title0': 'a1'}, {'test1': 'b2', 'title1': 'a2'}, {'title2': 'a3', 'test2': 'b3'}]
```

Comment: But what if one of the `i`s is missing?

Comment: @DYZ Check the start of my answer. I already mentioned that I am assuming that it won't happen that way. If it does, my answer won't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not so familiar with django, so there could be a more efficient way to do this, but...
You could do something like the following:

```
 query_result = request.GET.items()
 list_of_dicts = []
 for i in range(1, N):
     d ={'title'+str(i):d['title'+str(i)],'test'+str(i):d['test'+str(i)]}
     list_of_dicts.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cumbersome but still oneliner:

```
result = sorted([{k:v,"title"+k[4:]:d["title"+k[4:]]} for k,v in d.items() if k.startswith("test")],key=lambda x : sorted(x.keys()))
```

- create the sub-dicts with `testN` & corresponding `titleN` keys+values (shortcut: 4 is the length of `test` string)
- sort the list according to the sorted list of keys

result:

```
[{'test1': 'b', 'title1': 'a'}, {'test2': 'b', 'title2': 'a'}, {'titleN': 'a', 'testN': 'b'}]
```